# How can I hide the header on this Wordpress landing page using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site, and I want the user to be taken to a landing page before "entering" the website. On this landing page, I do not want the site header or footer to be visible.

I managed to hide the footer for only this page using the following code:

```
.page-id-4987 footer {
     display: none !important;
}
```

However, I've tried to do something similar for the header using various selectors, and seem to be targeting the wrong classes/elements/ids.

The website is: [staging.lyndsieanderson.com/escofferymusic/landing-page-bajc](http://staging.lyndsieanderson.com/escofferymusic/landing-page-bajc/)

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is very similar to a question recently asked here on StackOverflow. See the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416309/how-to-hide-header-on-specific-page-in-wordpress/43416476#43416476

Comment: If that answer works for you, give it an upvote. If it doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll help you solve it. However, it should work just the same, if you have a custom template for the page.

Comment: Also, the uri you give in your question, gives a 404.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add

```
Display:none;
```

to the `classic-menu` class. To do this you can add it to the page itself so that you don't override the entire class when you need to use the header on another page.