# How to hide header on specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to hide the header on a specific page in WordPress. I know that I can do this using CSS.

The page id as displayed in the dashboard is:

```
wp-admin/post.php?post=31221&action=edit
```

The page has a header without an id or class (not sure who built it). But I can hide the header with:

```
header {display: none;}
```

I can't seem to hide the header on the specific page. I have tried:

`.page-id-31221 header {display:none;}`
`.pageid-31221 header {display:none;}`

I have also tried the same with # and postid etc etc. Is there another way to hide the header on that page?

Failing that is there a way I can hide the header after it has been called in the template? I have created a custom template for the page but im not sure of the php to use to hide it. If I remove `<?php get_header();?>` from the template then the whole page disapears.

The website is here: [Website](http://qminmagazine.com/landing-page)

Comment: In your header.php file place an IF-statement `if(!is_page('PAGE_NAME_HERE')) { // show header }` Why pages are you trying to hide?

Comment: In the source code of the page you linked there is no `.page-id-31221` class. To add to what cosmoonot said, you could specify the page ID instead of the title, that way you won't have to worry about a page rename breaking the hide function.

Comment: I concur with @Optimae on page ID.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear. If I place `if(!is_page('.page-id-31221')) { // show header }` in header.php that will hide the header on that specific page?

Comment: This is easy to tackle with a custom template and JQuery. See my answer below, for a simple solution.

Comment: @GavinReynoldson NO! That is not your page ID, look in your wordpress admin panel, hover over the page link and you will see the PAGE ID attached. Use that INTEGER value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you have created a template for this specific page.

In which case you can use jQuery to hide the header. Add this to the end (or start) of your page template.

```
<script>jQuery('header').hide();</script>
```

You would probably want to wrap this inside something like a `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {` to ensure the page is loaded before the script is run. Maybe add in the defer attribute too.

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't thought of a simple jQuery script in the template. Worked a treat.

Comment: Glad it worked. Simple solutions are always the best.

Comment: That page will also have its own class, so no need for jQuery at all.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Does it?

Comment: If the template was created correctly the page body would have the class with the page name in it. Doesn't look like it's been done right.

Comment: See source here: http://reddragon.dirtandrust.com there is a body class "page-template-page-landingpage" which comes from the name of the php template I'm using for the landing page.

Comment: Yes, but there isn't in the case of the OP's scenario. Hence my use of JQuery is appropriate. Sure, recoding the page would also work, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your `header.php` by adding an IF-statement which checks for the required pages by either the **page/post ID** or **title**.

Page/Post ID method:

```
if(is_page(get_the_ID()) != YOUR_PAGE_ID) { // show header }
```

Page/Post Title method:

```
if(!is_page(get_the_ID('PAGE_POST_TITLE'))) { // show header }
```

Either of these methods should work. *Not tested.

Comment: This would require that the if statement is run on every page load of every page on the site, which is a small but unecessary hit to page load performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by checking the page name.

```
if( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) ){ #hide your header; }
```

If you want more details please read the wordpress official documentation. It will helpful for you.
[Read wordpress official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. A simple trick:

Check your style class name in your header.php in the top example: class="header">

And place this code in the top from your php template or page.

```
<head>
<style>
.header { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
```